# close ChildViewController in ChildViewController and go to Previous ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have added a view as ChildViewcontroller and I want to close it in ChildViewController only and go to Previous ViewController

Code from ParentViewController

```
 @IBAction func click_monday(_ sender: Any) {
    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .regular)
    let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
    blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
    blurEffectView.alpha = 0.8
    view.addSubview(blurEffectView)

    taskVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Task") as! TaskVC
    taskVC.view.backgroundColor = .clear
    taskVC.modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext

    taskVC.preferredContentSize = CGSize(width: 550.0, height: 400.0)
    self.view.addSubview(taskVC.view)
}
```

In TaskVC I have SaveButton which should close that View and go back to ParentViewController(editVC)

What I tried is

```
 @IBAction func click_save(_ sender: Any) {


    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "edit") as! editVC
     self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: false)

}
```

But its not working :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
 @IBAction func click_save(_ sender: Any) {
      self.view.removeFromSuperview()
      self.removeFromParentViewController()

      //self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true) //Add this if necessary
 }
```

Additional, if you want remove another view in the same super view, you could:

```
let blurView = self.view.superview?.viewWithTag(100)  //assume that blurView's tag is set before by: blurView.tag = 100 
blurView?.removeFromSuperview()
```

Comment: Super , This will remove the child View But blurEffectView is still their on top of editVC . Is it possible to remove blurEffectView in @IBAction func click_save of ChildVC ?

Comment: I have one more question : How can I change Image of a Button of ParentViewController from ChildViewController ?

Comment: @Spurti, same, the UIButton has the tag also. And it's better to callback ParentViewController by delegate or block if you have many things to do for ParentViewController.